# Unity 3d making a loop over time with floats

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, delay

I try to make a game where you can get money every 5 seconds. I tried coroutines invoked repeating and while in a coroutine so I can add value to a float and then after 5 seconds add value to it again but it doesn't work it will just add the value to the float without the delay please help.

> One example that didn't work:

```
        StartCoroutine(Job(2.0f));


void salary()
    {
        money += 10;
    }
    private IEnumerator Job(float waitTime)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

        //After waitTime, you can use InvokeRepeating() for infinite loop infinite loop or you use a while(true) loop here
        InvokeRepeating("salary", 0.0f, 2.0f);
    }
```

> Another example:

```
 StartCoroutine(Job(2));


    private IEnumerator Job(float waitTime)
{
    while (true)
    {
            money += 10;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    }
```

> And another example:

```
        StartCoroutine(Job());


IEnumerator Job()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            money += 10;

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to share your code, and how you call it, and make a [mcve] before people will give you a good answer

Comment: @BugFinder what about now?

Comment: What a complicated way of doing it.. OK.. so.. you started job as a coroutine.. for no real obvious reason... which waits for 2 seconds, then invokes money +10, after no wait and every 2 seconds..  Surely you just ditch job, and do InvokeRepeating("salary",5f,5f);

Comment: @BugFinder ... Here some other ways I tried are you pleased now :D

Comment: It also depends exactly where you are starting those coroutines of job...... if thats in update..

Comment: @BugFinder I start this in an if statement at update void

Comment: @BugFinder if statement is true

Comment: right but whats the if statement ?? if that is true your coroutine is being added to EVERY frame.... so you could have 10000s of them run  As explained - a [mcve] is the only way we can properly help you otherwise we are just guessing.. and posting one line thats part of another method, with other things with it.. is not complete

Comment: @BugFinder yeah so what should I do the if statement is `if(startship = true){ coroutine}`

Comment: please read all the comments above, it sounds like you just need to call the invokerepeating once.. at the start.. and not in update

Comment: @BugFinder and what about the if statement I want to start this loop every time the startship = true else I want to stop it(when startship = true get money per 10 sec when startship = false dont get money)

Comment: then you need to do something like if (startship) { startship=!startship; dostuff..} aa in update if you got 300fps, youre running that code 300x a second..

Comment: @BugFinder but this will stop another action if i turned it off whatever bye i will try another time

Comment: then it seems the wrong way to decide whether to do that action - however, you can put inside the invoke which is repeating every 5s, if (startship) money += 10; .....  but remember to only start it once.. like in start

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly what your code is doing with the three snippets provided, but what you say you are trying to accomplish is possible:

> I try to make a game where you can get money every 5 seconds.

Coroutines provide you with mechanisms to accomplish that.

Here is an example of how you might achieve the "while loop" solution for this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MakeMoneyEveryFive : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Money = 0;
    public float PayRate = 5;
    public bool IsWorking = true;

    private float timeBeforePay = 3;
    private float timeBetweenPay = 5;

    private void Start()
    {
        // You have to start your coroutine somewhere
        StartCoroutine(MakeMoney(timeBeforePay, timeBetweenPay));
    }

    public IEnumerator MakeMoney(float initialDelay, float delay)
    {
        // this wait statement can be helpful for fine tuning when your loop starts
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(initialDelay);

        // a variable as the loop condition allows you to exit when you want
        while (IsWorking)
        {
            // it's important Money is scoped to the class
            Money += PayRate;
            // delay inside loop runs every time, spacing out the additions to Money
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }
        // if you escape the loop (IsWorking == false) the coroutine will exit
        // you will need to start another if you want it to start again.
    }
}
```